# How to get state="completed" PayPal Payments

Tags: c#, paypal

I've received this JSON after execute a payment but the state remains "pending" how can i solve this in order to obtain "completed".

I've tried several things in order to make the payment but unsuccessfully

```
{
  "id": "PAY-2NU51454E4492922YKPZRNBA",
  "create_time": "2014-08-19T09:19:00Z",
  "update_time": "2014-08-19T09:19:32Z",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "severiano.testes@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "Diogo",
      "last_name": "Severiano",
      "payer_id": "MSQ6UB55W52N6",
      "shipping_address": {
        "line1": "1 Main Terrace",
        "line2": "",
        "city": "Wolverhampton",
        "country_code": "GB",
        "postal_code": "W12 4LQ",
        "state": "West Midlands"
      }
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "54.00",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "54.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "Transaction Description",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "1",
            "name": "Project Submission (featured)",
            "price": "54.00",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "sku": "27365"
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
          "recipient_name": "Diogo Severiano",
          "line1": "1 Main Terrace",
          "line2": "",
          "city": "Wolverhampton",
          "country_code": "GB",
          "postal_code": "W12 4LQ",
          "state": "West Midlands"
        }
      },
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "1BJ06026CY7370157",
            "create_time": "2014-08-19T09:19:00Z",
            "update_time": "2014-08-19T09:19:32Z",
            "amount": {
              "currency": "EUR",
              "total": "54.00"
            },
            "state": "pending",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-2NU51454E4492922YKPZRNBA",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1BJ06026CY7370157",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1BJ06026CY7370157/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2NU51454E4492922YKPZRNBA",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "state": "approved",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2NU51454E4492922YKPZRNBA",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using C# to make this:
 after using this the result is above.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(context.Session["RespostaJson"].ToString());                
                pymnt = new Payment();
                pymnt.id = data.id;
                PaymentExecution pymntExecution = new PaymentExecution();
                pymntExecution.payer_id = context.Request.Params["PayerID"];
                Payment executedPayment = pymnt.Execute(apiContext, pymntExecution);

                context.Response.Write(JObject.Parse(executedPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The receiver account (info.severiano-facilitator@gmail.com) has the primary currency set     
to USD but your transaction currency is in the EUR . Whenever you receive the payment in 
the currency that your account doesn't hold , you need to manually accept the transaction 
by logging to the account . Once you accept the payment PayPal will prompt you to either :

1. Deny the payment 
2. Or accept in the new currency and open the balance in the new currency 
3. Or accept the payment and convert the payment into your primary currency .

For now I have accepted the EUR currency( second choice 2.) for your sandbox account .   
Now you should be fine with your next payment and you will receive the Payment status    
as "completed ".
```